# Bar chart of counts of TRUE/FALSE data by group

Tags: bar-chart

I'm trying to make a ggplot2 bar plot in R with true/false data for 5 groups, but it's just plotting equi-spaced bars for 5 groups. My problem is similar to this one: ([Barchart of count of true/false values by group (dodged graphs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634136/barchart-of-count-of-true-false-values-by-group-dodged-graphs)); the solution to that one was to transform the data to long form and then apparently the usual geom_bar with stat="identity" plotted correctly. My data is already in long form, but I'm not getting a correct plot. The data is 2 column variables, Group and a column of TRUE/FALSE for each observation. I'm trying to plot a count of TRUE/FALSE for each group that would look about like the second graph in the other question.

```
    g = c(1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2) 
r = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
df = data_frame(g, r)
```

My plotting code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(g, r)) +  geom_bar(stat= "identity", position = "dodge")
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks for your help>

```
ggplot(df, aes(r)) + geom_bar() + facet_grid(. ~g)
```