# Count frequencies among columns and add to bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

First, I'd like to apologize if this has already been asked- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634136/barchart-of-count-of-true-false-values-by-group-dodged-graphs) question is somewhat similar but I still don't see how the poster was able to isolate, count, and graph the TRUE instances by "batch" in their code. I'm very new to RStudio and coding in general.

I would like to use RStudio to count frequencies among four columns of data and convert the counts into a bar graph. The data is structured as follows:

```
Column 1: 0,0,1,0,0,1...
Column 2: 1,0,0,0,0,0...
Column 3: 0,1,0,1,0,0...
Column 4: 0,0,0,0,1,0...
```

The .csv I'm working with lists each column separately. How do you count the "1" occurrences in each column and plot them on a bar chart (in ggplot2 specifically)? I want to format the graph so that each "column" is a variable on the x-axis and the frequency of "1" is represented on the y-axis.

It would be easiest to reformat the .csv in this case but unfortunately I am unable to edit the data file. It would be pointless for me to include the code I'm trying to use because its output is nothing close to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data frame looks something like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Column1 = c(0,0,1,0,0,1),
                  Column2 = c(1,0,0,0,0,0),
                  Column3 = c(0,1,0,1,0,0),
                  Column4 = c(0,0,0,0,1,0))
```

When working with data frames, it's useful to learn `dplyr` and `tidyr`. [Start here](https://www.tidyverse.org/) to learn about these tidyverse packages.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

Your data is "wide". It's better to make it "long", which means that there's a column for variable names and another for their values. Use `gather`:

```
df1 %>% 
  gather(Var, Val)
```

Now you can `count` by each variable and value:

```
df1 %>% 
  gather(Var, Val) %>% 
  count(Var, Val)

  Var       Val     n
  <chr>   <dbl> <int>
1 Column1     0     4
2 Column1     1     2
3 Column2     0     5
4 Column2     1     1
5 Column3     0     4
6 Column3     1     2
7 Column4     0     5
8 Column4     1     1
```

After that you can `filter` for rows where Val == 1 and pass that to `ggplot`:

```
df1 %>% 
  gather(Var, Val) %>% 
  count(Var, Val) %>% 
  filter(Val == 1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var, n)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: How do I format the data frame to match the example you give in step one? Each of those columns is a separate variable in my dataset.

Comment: If you're asking how to get the CSV file into R, start with `read.csv` (read the help using `?read.csv`).

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. The dataset has about 20 columns, but I am trying to isolate 4 of the columns to do the analyses on. How do I isolate those four columns out of the 20?

Comment: You can use `dplyr::select`. For example `df1 %>% select(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4)`.

Comment: Ok thank you, this has been incredibly helpful. The only thing is that I am unsure what to put in the "Var" part of the code because there are 4 different variables I'm working with.

Comment: `gather(Var, Val)` puts whatever column names you have into the new column `Var`.  For example `df1 %>% select(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) %>% gather(Var, Val)`.

Comment: Whenever I enter that command it tells me Error in gather(Var, Val) : object 'Var' not found

Comment: You need to pass the name of your data frame (_e.g._ `df1`) to `gather` using the pipe `%>%` symbol, as shown in the answer.