# Grouped relative barchart on binary encoded subcategories

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dataset with binary encoded subcategories A-I. If the Number is 1, a event in the given subcategory has occurred. Any combination is valid. Additionally, there are three different cases in the column "MyCases". It looks like this:

```
> dataset
       MyCases I H G F E D C B A
1     Case One 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
2   Case Three 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
3     Case Two 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
4     Case Two 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1
5     Case Two 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
6   Case Three 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
7     Case One 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
8     Case Two 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
9     Case Two 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
10    Case One 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
[...]
```

I was able to produce a barchart on absolute numbers [with the help of this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634136/barchart-of-count-of-true-false-values-by-group-dodged-graphs). Here's the code:

```
dataset %>%
 gather(key, value, -MyCases) %>%
 ggplot(., (aes(MyCases, as.numeric(value), fill = key))) +
  labs(
    title = "Chart of absolute numbers",
    x = "The three different cases", y = "absolute number of occurences"
  ) +
 stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "bar", position = "dodge")
```

You can see the resulting chart [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug8fh.png)

---

However, to be able to compare the three different cases I want to make the bars relational. I want to calculate the relative numbers for each of the different cases in "MyCases".

My Questions are:

1. How do I do this correctly?
2. How do I create the relative plot with ggplot2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before piping your data to `ggplot`, you can group and summarise them to find the proportion of events occurring within each category for each case.

```r
# data are already gathered
df <- data.frame(case=sample(1:3,500,T),
                 event.type=sample(letters[1:5],500,T),
                 event.value=sample(c(0,1),500,T))

df %>% group_by(case,event.type) %>% 
  summarise(n=sum(event.value)) %>% 
  mutate(prop=n/sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(case,prop,fill=event.type)) + geom_bar(stat='identity',position='dodge')
```

[image: bar]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.